# how to remove an element from a selection using Jquery/Javascript before appending to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, filter, prepend

I have a group of buttons, which I'm adding buttons to dynamically. My selection will look something like this:

```
$elements = [a.midToggle, a.menuToggle, a.ui-crumbs]
```

I want to prepend this selection to an existing controlgroup:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="dropZone">
   <a href="#" class="some">Some</a>
   <a href="#" class="midToggle">MidTog</a>
</div>
```

However before prepending, I want to remove the buttons already inside the controlgroup from my selection, because otherwise they will be in there multiple times.

I'm trying like this, but it doesn't work at all:

```
// I have multiple controlgroups, so I need to add the buttons to all of them
$('.dropZone').each(function() {     

   var $first = $(this), 
   $buttons = $elements.clone();

   $buttons.each(function() {
     // check if class name on new button is already in controlgroup
     if ( $(this).is(".midToggle") && $first.find(".midToggle").length > 0 ) {
     $(this).remove();
         }
      if ( $(this).is(".menuToggle") && $first.find(".menuToggle").length > 0 ) {
     $(this).remove();
         }
      if ( $(this).is(".ui-crumbs") && $first.find(".ui-crumbs").length > 0 ) {
     $(this).remove();
         }
      });
 // append what's left
 $first.append( $buttons )
```

I figure my *$buttons* aren't removed, but I don't know how to get it to work. Also my three if-statements are kind of lame. Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I had to modifiy the solution a little, because each button has multiple classes, so I cannot simply check for *attr('class')*. This is not perfect, but works:

```
function clearOut($what) {
    $buttons.each(function () {
        if ($(this).is($what)) {
            $buttons = $buttons.not($what)
            }
        });
     }

// filter for existing buttons
// TODO: improve
if ($first.find('.midToggle')) {
    clearOut('.midToggle');
    }
if ($first.find('.menuToggle')) {
    clearOut('.menuToggle');
    }
if ($first.find('.ui-crumbs')) {
    clearOut('.ui-crumbs');
    }
```

Comment: Why not keep them all in there and simply `hide()`/`show()` them?

Comment: @lila G: thought about that, too, but there may be buttons in there, that are constantly changing depending on what page I'm on. The three above are constant. Maybe should give this some more thought.

Comment: It'd be somewhat easier to first remove all buttons from the controls element, and then just add whatever buttons you want...

Comment: @frequent but that would be up to server side code to decide which buttons are applicable to which page... right?

Comment: @lila G. Keep bringing good arguments :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shrieked your code into half:

```
$('.dropZone').each(function() {
    var $dropZone = $(this);
    var $buttons = $elements.clone();
    $buttons.each(function() {
        var $button = $(this);

        if ($dropZone.find('.' + $button.attr('class')).length) 
            $button.remove();
    });

    $dropZone.append($buttons);
});​
```

Comment: @frequent. It's not the rep points that bothers me. I'm just curious why people accept answer without upvote it. Anyway I was glad to help.

Comment: @frequent. **:)** you made me laugh!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropZone').each(function() {     
   $buttons = $elements.filter(function() {
       if ($('.'+this.className).length) return this;
   });
   $(this).append( $buttons );
});
```